# Is there any Maven task for Spring Boot which works in the same way as Intelij Idea's 'run Application'?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have Spring Boot project, which builds typicaly with Maven. But there is a lot of plugins and tasks in my `pom.xml` so packaging project to .jar, and running on localhohst takes few minutes. In the same time, Intelij Idea has pre-defined run configuration, which calls `Application`. This configuration works very fast, and deploys only .java files, ommiting all Maven tasks.
How to do the same thing, as Idea does but using command line? Is there some Maven task, or should i just pack .jar manually?

[image]

Comment: `mvn spring-boot:run` if you have the Maven Spring Boot plugin in your `pom.xml` (which you will have by default if you generated the project from http://start.spring.io).

Comment: Your problem is that the `run` task does a lot more than you consider necessary to run the application. The solution involves investigating why this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Below command will do that

`mvn spring-boot:run`

Comment: This command runs all plugins and tasks included to pom.xml and works very slow. I need only to package my classes to .jar and run on localhost, as Idea does with 'Application' configuration.

Comment: "just packaging your class to jar" is more involved then you think. Compile, run tests, copy all dependencies to `BOOT-LIB`, create starter class, then package jar. The jar isn't just a jar with your classes it contains a lot more, and hence when running through maven it will do more. Also `spring-boot:run` doesn't create a jar it just runs the application after compiling, running tests, creating classpath. If you don't want tests then disable them using `-DskipTests`.